# Amateur equating powers question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I will admit to this being a rather amateur question that is fueled by total ignorance but can someone explain how i=-5/2,   j=1/2, and k=1/2 please? Thank you so so much in advance!

[image: HRK Page 8, sample problem 1-5]

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @user619894 I understand everything up to solving the three equations that equate to I=-5/2, j=1/2, and k=1/2. In other words, I do not know hot solve the three equations that are the exponents of L, T,and M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exponents of M we have $k=j$ and substituting into the other two equation gives:

$$ 0=i+5j$$

$$1=-i-3j$$

Can you end it now?